# TOAD For Oracle debugging: How to display the value of an attribute within a record

Tags: plsql, toad

Assume these Oracle type definitions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "FDS_APPS"."TY_AUDIT_COL_OBJ" AS OBJECT (
    application   VARCHAR2(30),
    module        VARCHAR2(30),
    created_by    VARCHAR2(50),
    creation_date DATE
);
        
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "FDS_APPS"."TY_AUDIT_COL_TBL" IS
    TABLE OF fds_apps.ty_audit_col_obj;
```

I am trying to use the TOAD for Oracle debugger to display the value of the expression `P_audit_col (1).Created_by`.  The only way that I currently able to do this is by moving this value to a varchar2 variable `Gvr_user`, then I can view the value by hovering over the variable.

I would like to not have to declare a temp variable just to assist in debugging. Is this possible in TOAD for Oracle?

```
 PROCEDURE Check_mv_status (
        P_audit_col      IN            Fds_apps.Ty_audit_col_tbl,
        P_refresh_ind    IN            CHAR DEFAULT 'N',
        P_mv_result         OUT NOCOPY Fds_apps.Ty_result_tbl)
    AS
        L_mv_stale_cnt        CHAR;
    BEGIN
        P_mv_result := Fds_apps.Ty_result_tbl ();                    
        P_mv_result.EXTEND (1);                                      


        Gvr_user := UPPER (P_audit_col (1).Created_by);
        Gvr_application := P_audit_col (1).Application;
```

Is this possible in Toad for Oracle 13.3 or any version?

Comment: This workaround from Toad 10 might still work. [How to see object type output in TOAD](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/how-to-see-object-type-output-in-toad/346360).

Comment: @JasonSeekWell - Thanks for the reply. Can you please check the link you provided? I get a "Oops! That page doesn’t exist or is private.". I would consider a work around a valid answer should you post an answer. ty!

Comment: The url is https://forums.toadworld.com/t/how-to-see-object-type-output-in-toad/34636

Comment: @JasonSeekWell - That was a very useful link but not exactly what I was looking for. I want to be able to query any property of a user Defined Type (UDT) while debugging, not just check on the contents of a returned UDT. But, nevertheless, it was still informative to find that I could convert a UDT to a refcursor and then use TOAD to display a REFCURSOR bound variable using this:   open :FINALIZE_REF for select * from table(V_TY_AUDIT_COL_TBL); I wish I could display multiple UDT returned values but the Dat Grid appears to be limkted to allowing only 1 refercursor result. ty!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that Toad for oracle does let you display the values of fields within a table of type.

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Perhaps I typed a watch expression as P_audit_col (1).Created_by instead of P_audit_col(1).Created_by, the difference being that, when I originally created the expression it had a space right before the "(1)" index. when I removed it, it works.